# Extraer arreglo de objetos como retorno de una promesa en Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objeto, jsonobject, jsonarray

Quisiera extraer un arreglo de objetos en javascript a partir de una promesa que consume los datos desde una API JSON.

De aquí consumo los datos: https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/37kkubt0chpmq/?cast_numbers=id,precio

Este arreglo es el que necesito tener en la variable "badeDeDatos":

```
[
 {"id":1,
 "nombre":"Papas",
 "precio":5,
 "image":"https:\/\/source.unsplash.com\/random\/500x500\/?potato&sig=1"
 },
 {"id":2,
 "nombre":
 "Zanahorias",
 "precio":3,
 "image":"https:\/\/source.unsplash.com\/random\/500x500\/?potato&sig=1"
 },
 {"id":3,
 "nombre":"Cebollas",
 "precio":4,
 "image":"https:\/\/source.unsplash.com\/random\/500x500\/?potato&sig=1"
 },
 {"id":4,
 "nombre":"Boniato",
 "precio":10,
 "image":"https:\/\/source.unsplash.com\/random\/500x500\/?potato&sig=1"
 },
 {
 "id":5,
 "nombre":"Acelga",
 "precio":5,
 "image":"https:\/\/source.unsplash.com\/random\/500x500\/?potato&sig=1"
 }
]
```

Este es el código que utilizo:

```
const baseDeDatos = fetch('https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/37kkubt0chpmq/?cast_numbers=id,precio')
 .then(async response => await response.json());
```

Y lo que recibo en la variable baseDeDatos es el arreglo dentro de la promesa:

```
Promise { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: (5) […] }

<value>: Array(5) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
​​
0: Object { id: 1, nombre: "Papas", precio: 5, … }
​​
1: Object { id: 2, nombre: "Zanahorias", precio: 3, … }
​​
2: Object { id: 3, nombre: "Cebollas", precio: 4, … }
​​
3: Object { id: 4, nombre: "Boniato", precio: 10, … }
​​
4: Object { id: 5, nombre: "Acelga", precio: 5, … }
​​
length: 5
​​
<prototype>: Array []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dado que [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) devuelve una promesa es necesario que el await lo hagas fuera, es decir, tienes que "esperar" a que fetch termine de obtener los datos. Dado que en JS, el `await` tiene que estar dentro de una función `async` por eso se implementa una función "padre".

Otra posible solución es que trabajes con el resultado dentro del `.then()`.

```js
async function fn () {
  const baseDeDatos = await fetch('https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/37kkubt0chpmq/?cast_numbers=id,precio').then(response => response.json());

  console.log(baseDeDatos);
}

fn();
```

Comment: Gracias, recién estoy comenzando con javascript. Al hacerlo así ahora tengo un arreglo efectivamente en la variable "baseDeDatos", pero al estar dentro de una función no puedo usarla afuera, Intenté varios intento con return pero no doy con la solución.

Comment: ¿no entiendo que quieres decir con que al estar dentro de una función no puedes usarla fuera?

Comment: la declaracion de la constante baseDeDatos esta dentro de otra funcion? si asi fuese puedes declarar la variable al comienzo del script y estara disponible globalmente